# Xamarin.Forms: What's the way to create Page based on MvvmCross ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Let's say I have my page defined as `public partial class MasterMenuPage : MvxContentPage<MasterMenuViewModel>`.

Is there any way to create that page in similar to Xamarin Native way:

```
 var creator = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxIosViewCreator>();
 loginController = (UIViewController) creator.CreateView(request);
```

I've found the following code to use:

```
  var request = new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(T));
  Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFormsPagePresenter>().CreatePage(..., request, new MvxMasterDetailPagePresentationAttribute());
```

However, I want MvvmCross to find out itself what type of the page to use instead of `...` (it must know that).